# Google Apps Script Error - Authorization is required to perform that action

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an Apps Script that replaces token in Google Doc. This App Script has been deployed as API Executable. I am able to run a function in the apps script editor without any authorization error. But, it fails sometimes with Authorization error when invoked from my java web application. I get the following error:

```
{
  "name": "replaceTokensInDoc",
  "done": true,
  "error": {
    "code": 3,
    "message": "ScriptError",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
        "errorMessage": "Authorization is required to perform that action.",
        "errorType": "ScriptError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have read in multiple places that I need to just run a function in Script Editor and provide permission to solve this issue, but it hasn't helped in my case. When I run a function in the editor, it doesn't even show the authorization dialog, which means it has all the necessary permissions. **It only fails sometimes.** Could somebody let me know the reason for this strange behavior?

Comment: Could you provide us the function you run ?

Comment: Sorry, It's a pretty big Apps Script (about 350 lines). At the high level, the inputs are Google Doc file ID and a JSON. The script parses thought the text in the google doc, gets the tokens and replace them with the value from input JSON.

Comment: There have been reports of problems with the Executable API recently.  But I have no way to know if it is related to you.  The following link may also be of interest.  [Link - Google Developers Blog - Updating developer identity guidelines and registration processes to protect users](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/updating-developer-identity-guidelines.html?m=1)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for this error is Google Apps Script return the Authorization error when the access token `expires_in` time is less than 6 minutes. The maximum time allowed for Apps Script execution is 6 minutes, so it wants to make sure that the token doesn't get expired while the Apps Script is being executed. This is a major issue in production. This should have been published in **bold** in the documentation.

There is an issue already created in the Google Issue tracker. Please star it if you are facing the same issue.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762863

The workaround, until the issue is resolved, is to refresh the token if the token expires in less than 360 seconds.

```
if (credential.getExpiresInSeconds() <= 360) {
    credential.refreshToken();
}
```

Comment: What would this code look like for python using oauth2client?

Answer (score 0):

python solution for execute.py sample (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/execute#step_4_make_the_scriptrun_request)

Basically if the expiry time is less than 361 seconds, then refresh the token

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient import errors
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
#from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file as oauth_file, client, tools
import sys
import datetime

def main():
    """Runs the sample.
    """
    SCRIPT_ID = 'YOUR SCRIPT ID' 

    # Setup the Apps Script API
    SCOPES = [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request'
        ,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
        ,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
        ,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts'
        ,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'
        ]
    store = oauth_file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    secondsDiff = (creds.token_expiry-now).total_seconds()

    print(secondsDiff)
    if secondsDiff < 361:
        http = creds.authorize(Http())
        creds.refresh(http)

    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('script','v1',credentials=creds)

    # Create an execution request object.
    request = {"function": "doGet", "parameters": [{"sheetId" : sys.argv[1]}]}

    try:
        # Make the API request.
        response = service.scripts().run(body=request,
                scriptId=SCRIPT_ID).execute()

        if 'error' in response:
            # The API executed, but the script returned an error.

            # Extract the first (and only) set of error details. The values of
            # this object are the script's 'errorMessage' and 'errorType', and
            # an list of stack trace elements.
            error = response['error']['details'][0]
            print("Script error message: {0}".format(error['errorMessage']))

            if 'scriptStackTraceElements' in error:
                # There may not be a stacktrace if the script didn't start
                # executing.
                print("Script error stacktrace:")
                for trace in error['scriptStackTraceElements']:
                    print("\t{0}: {1}".format(trace['function'],
                        trace['lineNumber']))
        #else:
        #    # The structure of the result depends upon what the Apps Script
        #    # function returns. Here, the function returns an Apps Script Object
        #    # with String keys and values, and so the result is treated as a
        #    # Python dictionary (folderSet).
        #    folderSet = response['response'].get('result', {})
        #    if not folderSet:
        #        print('No folders returned!')
        #    else:
        #        print('Folders under your root folder:')
        #        for (folderId, folder) in folderSet.iteritems():
        #            print("\t{0} ({1})".format(folder, folderId))

    except errors.HttpError as e:
        # The API encountered a problem before the script started executing.
        print(e.content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```